# jQuery nested call returning server error 500

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why this is happening, but the second jQuery call is giving a 500 error.  Is that because nested calls are not allowed? Or something else?  Thanks! Below is the whole code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function()
{
    $('#add_comment').bind('submit',function()
    //$("input[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
        var problem_id = $("#problem_id").val();
        var problem_comment = $("#problem_comment").val();  

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&problem_comment=' + problem_comment;

        if( problem_id == '' || problem_comment == '' )
        {   
            $('.comment_success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.comment_error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {   alert ("2");
            // Now check if the person is logged in.
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/auth/check_login.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert ("3");
                        // Now add the comment!
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/problems/add_problem_comment_ajax.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: dataString ,
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                $('.add_message_success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                $('.add_message_error').fadeOut(200).hide();

                                // Here can update the right side of the screen with the newly entered information
                                alert ("success");


                            },
                            error: function(data)
                            {
                                alert ("error");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(json)
                    {
                        alert ("error 2");
                        $("#loginpopup").dialog();

                        return false;           
                    }
            });         
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: HTTP 500s are server errors, so you're better off looking at the server code to find out what the problem is.  Make sure PHP logging is  enabled and configured and check the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a bug in this script: "/problems/add_problem_comment_ajax.php". You should check the error log to see the detailed error. The error log could be in the following places if you are using unix/linux/mac: `/var/log/httpd-error.log`, `/var/log/apache2/error_log`. If it's Windows, you should be able to view it in the event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

In the first AJAX CALL try adding **async:false,**:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "/auth/check_login.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data)
```

And try using FireBug (**Console** tab) to see what's on the POST and the RETURN of every AJAX call (you should see there that the second call return the error 500, look on the Post and Response of that call to search for something useful).

And as [Andy E.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) says that's an error on the server an exception,syntax,out of range or something on your PHP script.

Comment: nope - that didnt do the trick.  What was that supposed to do?

Comment: The default value to async is true,that it means that the AJAX call it's executed and the code continues, when is set it to false the code wait until the ajax call finish to continue it's execution. I had a problem that was fixed with this, because I use the result of the AJAX call but sometimes the code was executed faster than the AJAX call (so I was trying to use a result that I still didn't have ).